# Taylor series at $a=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find Taylor series representation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ for the function
\begin{equation*}
    f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^2}, & \text{ when } x \neq 0\\ 
    0, & \text{ when } x = 0,
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $a_n = \frac{f^n(0)}{n!}$.
I am confused by that when $x=0$, the function is also $0$. How to find Taylor series at $a=0$ for such a function? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: We define $f^{[n]}(0)$ as $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n}\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^2}}$. Continue with the usual Taylor series stuff from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n>0$.
For $x\ne 0$,

$$\sin(x)=x+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}+x^{2n+2}\epsilon(x)$$
thus

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k-1}}{(2k+1)!}+x^{2n}\epsilon(x).$$

with $$\lim_{x\to 0,x\ne 0}\epsilon(x)=0$$

$f$ is continuous at $x=0$, therefore

$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\; f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^{2k-1}}{(2k+1)!}+x^{2n}\epsilon(x)$$
with $\epsilon(0)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

You are right, at $x=0$ the function is $0$, but not its derivatives, as they are defined as a limit, so you should calculate the derivatives of the function at 0, using the regular rules. You will come by some indeterminate forms, such as $0/0$. You will have to see if the derivatives you calculate are continuous at $x=0$. When they stop being continuous, you will not be able to continue with the polynomial, so it will end there.
I hope that clears it to you.